# note and imageData in CNMutableContact and iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to fill the information of a CNMutableContact to save it and share it, and everything works perfectly except the note (that should be a regular String) and the imageData.

This is what i'm trying to do:

```
let contact = CNMutableContact()
contact.note = "HELLO"

if let imageUrl = self.getImgLogo(), let url = URL(string: imageUrl) {
    contact.imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
}
```

I set more things into the contact like the givenName, familyName, jobTitle, socialProfiles, phoneNumbers, emails, ... and everything works ok but those two things.

Anyone can tell me if am i doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the problem. The issue was related to the CNContactVCardSerialization that was ignoring the note and the imageData. So i made an extension to manage that problem:

```
import Contacts

extension CNContactVCardSerialization {
    
    
    class func dataWithExtraInformation(contacts: [CNContact]) throws -> Data {
        var text: String = ""
        for contact in contacts {
            let data = try CNContactVCardSerialization.data(with: [contact])
            var str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
            
            if let imageData = contact.imageData {
                let base64 = imageData.base64EncodedString()
                str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "END:VCARD", with: "PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=JPEG:\(base64)\nEND:VCARD")
            }
            
            if !contact.note.isEmpty {
                str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "END:VCARD", with: "NOTE:\(contact.note)\nEND:VCARD")
            }
            
            text = text.appending(str)
        }
        return text.data(using: .utf8)!
    }
}
```

It just gets the serialized card and adds the extra information that i needed ;)

Thanks!